# Payment with Braintree retrieving data from vault

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, braintree

I first created a customer with the help of API, when a customer created successfully then it returned me customerId, with the help of customerId I created a credit card.

```
// for creating user
gateway->customer()->create([
        'firstName' => $firstName,
        'lastName' => $lastName,
        'company' => $company,
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'fax' => $fax,
        'website' => $website
        ]);

//for creating card
$result = $this->gateway->creditCard()->create([
        'customerId' => $customerId,
        'number' => $number,
        'expirationDate' => $expirationDate,
        'cvv' => $cvv
```

After saving card in vault successfully it gives me a **token** In order to retrive data of card I did this:

```
$result = $this->gateway->creditCard()->find($token);
```

and it returned me the card detail, Now I want to perform payment with this card detail or token(as I am confused). previously I successfully done payment with **drop in UI** but I want to use vault this time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

Now that you have the [payment method token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method/python#token), you can pass that value as a parameter to the [Transaction Sale API Call](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php) in order to complete a transaction with the saved payment method as opposed to a [payment method nonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-method-nonces), which represents a single use payment method.

**Example**

```
$result = $gateway->transaction()->sale(
  [
    'paymentMethodToken' => 'the_payment_method_token',
    'amount' => '100.00'
  ]
);
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing......what is the major difference between  payment_token and payment_nonce ?

Comment: They both represent encrypted payment information, but the major difference is that a payment_method_token can be used multiple times to charge that payment method and is stored in the Braintree Vault for future use. The payment method nonce, however, expires after 3 hours. 

In order to save a payment method int he Braintree Vault, you initially need to generate and pass a payment method nonce in the Customer create or Payment Method Create API Call, but after that, you can use the resulting payment method token.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-method-nonces